# Guzzle response with content-encoding: gzip comes back with incorrect content-length header

Tags: php, json, gzip, guzzle, content-length

I have a symfony2 application where I am using the Guzzle http client to send a GET request to a server in order to retrieve the contents of a json file. The Guzzle response gets transformed into a Symfony2 response to the browser.

The Guzzle response comes back with the following headers:

Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 2255
Content-Type: application/json

When outputting the data to the UI/browser I notice that it gets cut off because the Content-Length is incorrect. The size of the file is closer to 4905 bytes, not 2255. 2255 is the exact length of the data up to the cut-off point. I suspect that the 2255 is the size of the gzipped data and it gets uncompressed at some point without updating the content-length. Now I did verify that I get all of the data back, however the content-length header is honored which is why the data gets cut off when I forward it to the browser. Interestingly, hitting the url to the json file directly yields the full contents even though the content-length is 2255 which means it gets ignored by Chrome when hitting the file directly. Same if I use the POSTman REST client to make the GET request - full contents get displayed.

By default, Guzzle has a request option decode_content = true for how the responses should be handled. I set it to false when submitting the request but that didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Before converting the Guzzle response to a Symfony response I removed the content-length header and that seems to solve the problem however I am not sure that's the best approach since RFC protocol states that a content-length header should be present unless a transfer-encoding header is present, which it isn't. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html

Another alternative is, since this is a streamed response, to get the size of the stream and correct the content-length, however the Guzzle implementation uses strlen() for this which has the undesirable affect of reading the whole stream.

What possible issues might I run into if I choose to omit the content-length header? And alternatively, is there a way to get the TRUE length of the contents without reading the whole stream and simply update the content-length header with the correct amount?